# RewriteRule for HTTP to HTTPS and WWW ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I've trawled many forums and tried many solutions. None work correctly. I am using ISAPI Rewrite 3 for IIS.

I need to change all requests to our website to WWW and HTTPS.

For example:

- http**s**://example.com/a-page-here/
- http://example.com/a-page-here/
- http://www.example.com/a-page-here/
- www.example.com/a-page-here/
- example.com/a-page-here/

to all change to:

- https://www.example.com/a-page-here/

I've used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be, which may be buggy because I'm getting seemingly incorrect results for so-called working solutions. I don't want to be testing umpteen things on the live site.

This supposedly correct example (one of many) I found gives incorrect results:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
# Extract non-www portion of HTTP_HOST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*) [NC]
# Redirect to HTTPS with www
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%2/$1 [R=301]
```

Example tests:

- **example.com/a-page-here/** = **https://www./example.com/a-page-here**
- **www.example.com/a-page-here/** = **https://www./www.example.com/a-page-here/**

Can anyone give me a set of rules that will cleanly and reliably turn any non www request to our website to the correct **https://www** version, and not add invalid slashes etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https\://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]

# HTTP to HTTPS 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https\://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```